# Как понять callback java

Tags: java, callback

Всё что нашёл, первых 5 страниц выдачи, половина из них javascript, код которого я не понимаю, а половина муть какая-то, когда с первых предложений начинают лезть в какие-то дебри, например "Берём win srpt Api и в нём функция GGDT через SMLP.." И всё в таким же духе. И вообще, при чём тут интерфейс?

На занятиях тоже отвратительно объяснили

> Зачастую, это используется при создании так называемых колбэков - объектов, которые определяются в классе А и передаются в качестве аргумента в класс Б

Помогите, дайте простой пример, если можно с кодом

Например: Есть 2 человека, Петя и Маша, и если Петя ударил Машу (произошло событие) - нужно Петю наказать.

Comment: Не знаю как конкретно в `Java`, но коллбэк - это обычно ссылка на функцию. Вы передаёте эту ссылку в какой-то вызываемый вами метод и этот метод при определённых условиях вызывает функцию, ссылку на которую вы ему передали. Например, это используется для таймеров - вы передаёте ссылку на функцию, которую таймер вызовет по прошествии какого-то времени. Коллбэки могут вызываться и по другим событиям - окончание загрузки страницы, ошибка, и т.д.

Comment: На практических занятиях разберётесь. А если таких не будет, то просто заучите перед экзаменом определение, которое дал учитель:)
Что касается java, то в старых учебниках по java часто рассказывали про listener-ы и observer-ы. Это и есть пример callback-а.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Колбэки делаются через интерфейсы.

В примере ниже, когда 1 человек бьет другого, у нас еще есть колбэк, из которого мы можем посмотреть "а какой урон был у жертвы нападения?"

а так же сам колбэк возвращает нам в место его вызова какую-то строку, которую мы можем использовать в коде в дальнейшем.

```
    public class Human {

    public String name;
    public int damage;

    public Human(String name, int damage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public void fight(Human otherHuman, FightCallback callback) {
        LogUtilsKt.logInfo(name + " наносит " + damage + " урона по " + otherHuman.name);
        String str = callback.fight(otherHuman.damage);
        LogUtilsKt.logInfo(str);
    }

}


public interface FightCallback {
    String fight(int otherHumanDmg);
}


public class main {
    public main() {
    }

    public static void main() {
        Human a = new Human("Petya", 42);
        Human b = new Human("Mashа", 12);
        a.fight(b, new FightCallback() {
            @Override
            public String fight(int otherHumanDmg) {
                LogUtilsKt.logInfo("" + otherHumanDmg);
                return "Wlad";
            }
        });
    }
}
```